# Capture output of curl sub shell?

Tags: bash, curl

I've got a curl command like so:

```
curl -v --silent --tlsv1.1 https://google.com/ 2>&1 | grep TLS
```

I'd like to capture the output of that command in a variable. Normally I'd use a subshell to do this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
OUT=$(curl -v --silent --tlsv1.1 https://google.com/ 2>&1 | grep TLS)
echo $OUT
```

but the command outputs the following (if I'm in a directory with a single file in it called "UNEXPECTED.TXT").

> UNEXPECTED.TXT TLS 1.0 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

So it seems to do a directory listing of the current directory, then append my output to the end of that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
echo "$OUT"
* TLS 1.1 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Since variable `OUT` has a starting `*`, **without quotes** shell is expanding first `*` to all the files/directories in your current path and listing all the files/directories.

Comment: Ahhh... That makes sense! Thanks!